# Javascript conditional calculation system

Tags: javascript, calculator

This is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ins-feet").value;

    if(x>=0 && x<=1499) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 300;
    } else if(x>=1500 && x<=1999) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 320;
    } else if(x>=2000 && x<=2500) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 340;
    } else if(x>2500) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 340;
    }

}
```

Need assist in last line. When x>2500 id "show-cost" will show 340 + 0.10 for every additional increment. ie, x>2501 = 340.1, x>2502 = 340.2 and so on.

Comment: `"Cost: $" + (340 + 0.1 * (x - 2500))` Looks simple enough. Did I miss something ?

Comment: here is an issue. as this code when x = 2504 output cost is $3400.4

Comment: it should 340.4

Comment: If you tried the operation I wrote 2 minutes ago, try again, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes thanks. its right now

Comment: I wrote an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I not really that difficult :

You need the difference between `x` and 2500, then do a simple subtraction.

Then multiply `0.1` by that difference, like so :

```
340 + 0.1 * (x - 2500)
```

Now just to be sure to prevent concatenating, you put that in parenthesis :

```
"Cost: $" + (340 + 0.1 * (x - 2500))
```

So you will have this :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ins-feet").value;

    if(x>=0 && x<=1499) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 300;
    } else if(x>=1500 && x<=1999) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 320;
    } else if(x>=2000 && x<=2500) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + 340;
    } else if(x>2500) {
        document.getElementById("show-cost").innerHTML = "Cost: $" + (340 + 0.1 * (x - 2500));
    }

}
```